# Problem with understanding the code of 968. Binary Tree Cameras

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am studying algorithms and trying to solve the LeetCode problem [968. Binary Tree Cameras](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-cameras/):

> You are given the `root` of a binary tree. We install cameras on the tree nodes where each camera at a node can monitor its parent, itself, and its immediate children.
>
> Return *the minimum number of cameras needed to monitor all nodes of the tree*.

I got stuck on it, and after checking the discussion I better understood the logic, but I am still struggling to understand the code:

```py
def minCameraCover(self, root):
    self.res = 0
    def dfs(root):
        if not root: return 2
        l, r = dfs(root.left), dfs(root.right)
        if l == 0 or r == 0:
            self.res += 1
            return 1
        return 2 if l == 1 or r == 1 else 0
    return (dfs(root) == 0) + self.res
```

I don't understand why `l, r == 0, 0` in a DFS function while  the base case is set as `if not root: return 2`

What are the mechanics behind this that makes `dfs(root.left), def(root.right)` return 0?

So far I understood that a node has three states:

- 0: it's a leaf
- 1: it has a camera and the node is parent of a leaf
- 2: it's being covered, but does not have a camera on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case is set for a `None`, i.e. the absence of a node. Such a *virtual* position is never a problem, so we can count it as "covered", but there is no camera there. This is why the base case returns 2.

Now when a leaf node is encountered, then obviously both recursive calls will get `None` as argument and return 2.

Then the expression `2 if l == 1 or r == 1 else 0` will evaluate to 0, as neither `l` nor `r` are 1 (they are 2): the`else` clause kicks in.

I hope this clarifies that for leaf nodes the return value will be 0, but also for other nodes this can happen: every time both recursive calls return 2, the caller will itself return 0.

Therefore the better explanation of the three states is:

- 1: the node has a camera
- 2: the node has no camera, but it is covered from below
- 0: the node has no camera yet and is not covered from below. If it has a parent, that parent should get a camera so to cover for this node. It it is the root, it must get a camera itself.

Comment: Thank you so much, You saved my day! I got stuck for so long TAT. I use to do simple DFS that all conditions are listed above, but in this case the result of the minor case is also part of the conditions, I think I start to get it. I will try to slove it by myself until I fully figuer it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it was useful!

Comment: Done! I am still learning the feature of stackflow, the answer absolutely helps a lot. I can't upvote though I dont have enough reputation.